# Reorder words in each element of a vector

Tags: r, regex, lapply, stringr, strsplit

I'd like to change the word order for each element in a vector. Specifically I'd like to make another vector where the first word is now the last word for a number of elements that differ in length.

**Data**

```
metadata1 <- c("reference1 an organism", 
               "reference2 another organism here",
               "reference3 yet another organism is here")
```

**Desired outcome**

```
metadata2 <- c("an organism reference1", 
               "another organism here reference2",
               "yet another organism is here reference3")
```

**My attempt**

```
metadata2 <- lapply(strsplit(metadata1," "), function(x) paste(x[c(2,3,4,5,1)]))
```

I've tried to use `lapply()` to separate each element by spaces using `strsplit()`, and then paste them back together using the order index. This gets the words in the right order, but returns a list where the words are separate elements and because some elements are longer than others I get "NA"s when an index number is higher than the number of words in that element. I've also tried `sapply()` which returns a matrix and `tapply()` which does not work.

Comment: One standard way: `sub("^(\\w+) (.*)$", "\\2 \\1", metadata1)`

Comment: @Frank that's a brilliant solution too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
paste(word(metadata1,2, -1), word(metadata1,1), sep = " ")
# [1] "an organism reference1"                 
# [2] "another organism here reference2"       
# [3] "yet another organism is here reference3"

# OR

sapply(metadata1, function(x){ y = unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
                           paste(c(y[-1],y[1]),collapse = " ")
                           })


# OR ( this is purely @Frank's answer)( Shall remove when he puts it as an answer)
sub("^(\\w+) (.*)$", "\\2 \\1", metadata1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and precise response! I went with the `stringer::word()` solution because it allows me to realign the metadata with the data more easily.