# Sorting based on % symbol within a single cell - R

Tags: r, regex, sorting, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` containing cells like this:

```
df<-as.data.frame(c('10% - 34', '15.5% - 15:4', '18% - 1n9'))
```

I would like to `sort` within each cell so that the percentage value is on the right, to become:

`34 - 10%`, `15:4 - 15.5%`, `1n9 - 18%`

I have tried splitting each by the `'-'` delimiter and pasting back together, but is there a more efficient way for large `data.frame`s? Thank you

Comment: If the sorting is based on the presence of percentage values, it is better to include it in the title to make it clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reorder words in each element of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009315/reorder-words-in-each-element-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular expression where we reverse the elements might be more efficient than splitting and re-pasting.

```
sub("(.+%) - (.*)", "\\2 - \\1", df[[1]])
# [1] "34 - 10%"     "15:4 - 15.5%" "1n9 - 18%"
```

Here we capture the first and last elements in the `pattern` argument, then swap them in the `replacement` argument.

Regex explanation courtesy of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3mC6cI/1):

- `(.+%)` is the 1st Capturing Group; `.+` matches any character (except for line terminators);  `+` is a quantifier. It matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy); `%` matches the character % literally (case sensitive); `-` matches the characters `-` literally (case sensitive)
- `(.*)` is the 2nd Capturing Group; `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators); `*` is a quantifier.  It matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

The replacement string `"\\2 - \\1"` puts the second capturing group (`\\2`) first, then literal `-`, then the first capturing group (`\\1`).  See `help(regex)` for more.